# Test set Target encoding with the label mean

Tags: encoding

I found that both train and test set target encoding with label mean should be done based on train set target values so that we do not leak train set information into test set.

I am performing target encoding over my dataset based on the train set label means, but since the data set is time series and one of the variables to encode is "Year", the last two years of my data goes to test set and does not get the encoded values, results in NA. How should we encode those values in test set that are not present in train set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. After no body answered this question and I worked around the problem. I found the solution. The answer is that it is not possible to do target encoding for the "Year" feature in time series problem, since years are identical and there may be no characteristics repeated from previous years, in contrast with "Mount" or "Week Number" features. So, one of the better ways is to do is One-hot encoding. I have to mention that, this problem is valid only for the cases where the date feature is considered to be a categorical attribute.